# Dota 2 matchmaking server priority

Tags: dota-2

In Dota 2 when you select more than one server region and start the matchmaking, the background image has only US West server colored. Is that actually a map bug or does the game really search the US West server first and then other locations? Or are they all grouped together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is merely a visual glitch; the background image does not correctly reflect your selected regions. Accurate feedback is available from the options sidebar, which properly lists the selected regions.